# SSRS-Report -How to get table name from parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to get table name from parameters, then i will use that to my query like

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(100)
declare @tableName nvarchar(100) 
select @cmd = ' select * from '  + @tableName
execute (@cmd)
```

when i try to run with query designer dataset, it popup error message like

```
the declare sql construct or statement is not supported
```

What am I missing that needs to be there or what is causing this issue?
i hope somebody can give a hand how to solve it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the query designer that cannot support this for obvious reasons. Just click "Edit as text" in the top left corner of the query designer and then you can do whatever you like.

Just remember that your dataset must always return the same column names in the same order with the same datatypes.

Comment: i can run it without message error, thanks for that advice. but it showing nothing on the table. it's must be showing my data id, x y and value. my code right or miss something??

Comment: The code looks OK but to test what is being executed, add `SELECT @cmd as myCmd` to the end of the code. Then add a text box to your report and drag the myCmd field to it. Then you can see what it being executed.

Comment: BTW: If the original question is answered, please mark this as accepted. If you have a separate question (like the one you are asking now) you should start a new question.

Comment: sorry i am new student here, thanks. i'll close it then

Comment: Actually the code is wrong. You are not setting @tablename anywhere. If the is coming from the report as a parameter then you must not declare in your code. Also, the name must be exactly the same as the parameter name in the report, it is case sensitive.

Comment: can i get help how i must write my code, i want test it my query designer, when it get right result i will set parameters for table name later

Comment: just add a line somehting like `SET @tablename = 'dbo.MyTableNameHere'` before the select statement